# How can the fact an electron is in a stable orbit eliminate kinetic energy from the total energy formula?

Tags: atomic-physics

Since the potential of a point charge with respect to another is

$F=k\dfrac{Q_1Q_2}{r}$,

where $k=\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$,

the potential of an orbital electron is

$V=-k\dfrac{Ze^2}{r}$,

where Z is the number of protons in the nucleus.

Therefore, the total energy of an electron is given by

$E=E_K+E_P$

$E=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2+(-\dfrac{kZe^2}{r})$

This I understand, but then the textbook says

> Because the electron is in a stable trajectory, this becomes
>   $E=-\dfrac{kZe^2}{2r}$.

How can the fact that it's a stable trajectory eliminate the kinetic energy from the total energy formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess the book is using the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem), which states that for a stable system:

$$ 2T = -V $$

This immediately gives us $T = kZe^2/2r$ and therefore the total energy is $T + V = -kZe^2/2r$.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: 
Since electron is revolving in a circular orbit, the electrostatic force of attraction between proton and electron provides the necessary centripetal force.

(For simplicity, I have chosen a hydrogen atom system)

${mv^2\over r}$= ${ke^2\over r^2}$

This implies: $v^2 = {ke^2\over mr}$

As $K.E.$= $\frac12\ m v^2$

So,
$K.E. $= ${ke^2\over 2r}$

Now, as you already know, $P.E$= ${-ke^2\over r}$
Hence, Total energy = $P.E. + K.E$= ${-ke^2\over r}$